Problem in Distributed Tracing over WebSocket with STOMP: Transitioning from Sleuth to Micrometer, Trace IDs and Span IDs does not appear
I have been working on a project implemented using Spring Boot 2.7.8. The WebSocket protocol was chosen to handle real-time messaging, and STOMP over WebSocket is used for effective client-server communication. For distributed tracing, Spring Cloud Sleuth has been utilized. When the project runs, Sleuth works flawlessly, and trace IDs and span IDs are propagated to the logs.
As the project required, I attempted to upgrade the Spring Boot version to 3.3.2. Following the Spring documentation, I replaced Sleuth with Micrometer. However, when the project runs and WebSocket API calls are made, no trace IDs or span IDs show up in the logs.
I have searched many articles to find a solution, but none have provided an answer. I would appreciate any ideas anyone might have.
